# How to configure CLion IDE for Qt Framework?

Tags: c++, qt, clion

How to configure CLion IDE for Qt Framework?
Is this IDE compatible with Qt, or are there other IDEs compatible with Qt?

I just want to try to use something else than Qt Creator.

Comment: I don't think this question is worthy of this kind of downvotes. While the answer is able to be found through a google search, it requires quite a bit of clicking around. Finding this let me get the answer much faster.

Comment: @Claudio The question wasn't about which IDE is the best, but how CLion can work with Qt. Your reply isn't helping to answer this thread, nor those who want to develop with Qt without having to use Qt Creator.

Comment: Note that there is (now) an official page from Jetbrains about this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html

Answer (score 60):

I was as desperate as you, until I read [this Quora discussion](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-setup-CLion-to-work-with-the-Qt-framework).
It worked perfectly for me!

To summarize, there are 2 main steps:

Firstly, CLion uses CMake to compile your code. It is based on CMake configuration files (e.g "CMakeLists.txt"). You have to add Qt based CMake commands (the lines with 'find_package' and 'target_link_libraries'):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(myqtproject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)                 <-- this line

add_executable(myqtproject ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(myqtproject Qt5::Widgets)   <-- this line
```

Secondly, CLion has to use the `cmake` binary installed by Qt. For that, go to:
'Preferences' -> 'Build, Execution, Deployment' -> 'CMake' and in 'CMake options' append the CMake path that Qt uses, which should be in the directory where Qt is installed. For instance, on OSX:

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/edouard/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/cmake
```

You can test that everything is working fine, by doing a little test script in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    qDebug() << QT_VERSION_STR;
    return 1;
}
```

Which should display something like:

```
/Users/edouard/Library/Caches/CLion2016.2/cmake/generated/myqtproject-89a4132/89a4132/Debug/untitled
5.7.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**UPDATE**

I was stuck with the problem of adding Qt5 modules (for instance QSql). You can do this by adding in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Qt5Sql REQUIRED)
```

just after the other `find_package`, and adding in the last line:

```
target_link_libraries(myqtproject Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Sql)
```

You can do this with all the other Qt5 modules.

Answer (score 40):

**UPDATE**

There is an now an official tutorial on the Jet Brain website:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html

**Original answer**

This approach is one of the simplest way to be used for the newest *Qt* version.

```
Qt:    5.10.1
CLion: 2018.1.2
GDB:   8.1
```

**Project setup**

In *CLion*:

1. Create a *C++ Executable*/*Library* project
2. Use this sample "*CMakeLists.txt*" for common console/gui projects that uses: *QtCore*, *QtWidgets* and *QtQuick*

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(PROJECT_NAME)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "PATH_TO_QT/QT_VERSION/QT_ARCH/lib/cmake")

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)

add_executable(PROJECT_NAME main.cpp MainWindow.cpp MainWindow.h qml.qrc)

target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME Qt5::Core)
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME Qt5::Quick)
```

- Resource files (.qrc) should be added to add_executable list, in
  order for moc to be able to run its procedure on the resource and the
  internal file like qmls, texts, ... be accessible.
- qml files should be included in a qrc file and load using *QQmlApplicationEngine* at runtime

**Debuger:**

In order to has a human-readable view in debug sessions from Qt types, A new GDB must be installed on the system and pretty printers must be available:

Pretty printers for Qt5:

1- *Lekensteyn* *Qt5 Pretty Printers* (Working):

Address: https://github.com/Lekensteyn/qt5printers

Setup: ~/.gdbinit

```
python
import sys, os.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser('~/.gdb'))
import qt5printers
qt5printers.register_printers(gdb.current_objfile())
end
```

2- Official (not working!!!):

```
"PATH_TO_QT/QT_VERSION/QT_ARCH/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/debugger/"
```

Setup: ~/.gdbinit

As stated in included readme file (but not working!):

```
python sys.path.insert(1, '<path/to/qtcreator>/share/qtcreator/debugger/')
python from gdbbridge import *
```

**External tools**

In "File -> Settings -> Tools -> External Tools", add 4 external tools:

Qt Creator:

```
Program:   "PATH_TO_QT/QT_VERSION/QT_ARCH/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator"
Arguments: $FilePath$
```

UI Designer:

```
Program:   "PATH_TO_QT/QT_VERSION/QT_ARCH/lib/bin/designer")
Arguments: $FilePath$
```

LUpdate:

```
Program:   "PATH_TO_QT/QT_VERSION/QT_ARCH/lib/bin/lupdate")
Arguments: $FilePath$ -ts $FileNameWithoutExtension$.ts
```

Linguist:

```
Program:   "PATH_TO_QT/QT_VERSION/QT_ARCH/lib/bin/linguist")
Arguments: $FilePath$
```

Now you can right click these file types and under the external tool:

1. For .ui select *Qt Creator*/*Designer* and start UI designing
2. For .qml select *Qt Creator* and design UI in QML editor
3. For .qrc select *Qt Creator* and use resource editor
4. For .cpp/.ui select *LUpdate* to create its translation file
5. For .ts select *Linguist* and start the translating

**Automatic Beautifier**

If in *Qt Creator* you used a beautifier like "Uncrustify" to auto beautify the code on saving a source file, then:

1. Install the plugin "*Save Actions*"
2. Under the "File -> Settings -> Save Actions"
3. Check:
4. *Active save actions on save*
5. *Reformat file*
6. For best performance un-check:
7. *Organize imports*

Answer (score 6):

As Tom Lank mentions, Qt projects can now be managed with, and built under CMake, which makes CLion happy.

[Qt5's CMake manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) describes how. Qt provides a lot of magic under the hood here, and it's explained much better in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html).

One thing that isn't mentioned in the Qt CMake manual or above is that you'll also need the lines:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) # if you have any .ui files
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON) # if you have any .qrc files
```

All of these calls to `set()` should probably come before the line `find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)`. Also include any .ui or .qrc files as dependencies in the call to `add_executable()` along with your .cpp files.

This was initially very confusing to me from browsing the web, but you shouldn't need any calls to `qt_*()` or `qt5_*()`. These have been superseded so far as I can tell.

To test that your `CMakeLists.txt` actually works correctly, you can try building within Qt Creator, by loading `CMakeLists.txt` as a project and building.

Once confirmed, you can load the `CMakeLists.txt` file as a project in CLion.
Most likely, you'll need to tell CMake where to find your Qt packages with a line like this before your `find_package`'s:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/5.9/msvc2015_64")
```

Finally, if you're running on / building for windows, Qt no longer comes pre-built with GCC/Mingw32 libraries. You need to build with visual studio. Luckily, [CLion now supports Visual Studio experimentally](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/02/clion-2017-1-eap-first-steps-to-asm-and-msvc) and I've found it to work for Qt projects; just be sure to set the architecture (under Settings->Build, Execution, Development->CMake) to x86_amd64, in order to build in 64-bit mode and be compatible with Qt's pre-build libs.

All of this is tested with CLion 2017.1, Qt 5.9, and the Visual Studio 2015 compiler.

Comment: This was the simplest and quickest solution for me

Answer (score 2):

You can build QT applications in CLion. 
QT Provides CMake modules that take care of all details.

The following CMake script builds the example application '[Dynamic Layouts Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-dynamiclayouts-example.html)'

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(qtlayoutexample)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Find QT packages
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# Add the include directories for the Qt 5 Widgets module to
# the compile lines.
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Add compiler flags for building executables (-fPIE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

qt5_generate_moc(main.cpp main.moc)

# Tell CMake to create the qtlayoutexample executable
add_executable(qtlayoutexample main.cpp dialog.cpp main.moc)

#Link the qtlayoutexample executable to the Qt 5 widgets library.
target_link_libraries(qtlayoutexample Qt5::Widgets)
```

More information [regarding building Qt applications with CMake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html).

Answer (score 2):

This link has a quickstart project, you just have to change your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in CMakeLists to the location of the Qt packaged compiler you want to use (mine is gcc_64, his by default is clang_64)-- it has some of the settings mentioned by other answers already set:

https://github.com/ArneGockeln/qtstarter

In addition, (on Ubuntu-based Linux) I had to install the OpenGL libraries as described here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/11378/how-do-i-set-up-an-opengl-programming-environment).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to add QT install `..Qt\5.10.1\mingw53_32\bin;` to your PATH. Don't forget to restart PC afterwards, because CLion for some reason isn't able to refresh the path, only full pc restart helps.