# Unable to link CLion to QT On Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, cmake

Im trying to link Qt Creator to Clion so i can use it for creating GUI elements but the only information I was able to find on doing this was this thread

[How to configure CLion IDE for Qt Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235175/how-to-configure-clion-ide-for-qt-framework)

I tried to follow this as closely as possible but one of the major differences is that on windows there is no clang_64 file instead it is msvc2017_64 and that is what seems to be showing up in the error im getting.

My CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(helloqt)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(helloqt ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(helloqt Qt5::Widgets)
```

my main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    qDebug() << QT_VERSION_STR;
    return 1;
}
```

under Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake my Cmake Options has the path

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Qt/5.12.1/msvc2017_64/lib/cmake
```

and it results in this error which I have not been able to find a fix to.

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Uncorropto\CLionProjects\helloqt\cmake-build-debug --target helloqt --
Scanning dependencies of target helloqt
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/helloqt.dir/main.cpp.obj
main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable helloqt.exe
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1414~1.264\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\helloqt.dir\objects1.rsp /out:helloqt.exe /implib:helloqt.lib /pdb:C:\Users\Uncorropto\CLionProjects\helloqt\cmake-build-debug\helloqt.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Guid.lib C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\helloqt.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\helloqt.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QMessageLogger::QMessageLogger(char const *,int,char const *)" (__imp_??0QMessageLogger@@QAE@PBDH0@Z) referenced in function _main
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QDebug __thiscall QMessageLogger::debug(void)const " (__imp_?debug@QMessageLogger@@QBE?AVQDebug@@XZ) referenced in function _main
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QDebug::~QDebug(void)" (__imp_??1QDebug@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QDebug & __thiscall QDebug::operator<<(char const *)" (__imp_??6QDebug@@QAEAAV0@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Guid.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
helloqt.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't find symbol like [QMessageLogger](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagelogger.html) which is part of  [Qt Core](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-index.html). Note you have used `qDebug()` which refers to this symbols!

Conclusion is simple add this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED) # this might be not needed
target_link_libraries(helloqt Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)
```

**Offtopic**: trash this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Like this? `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(helloqt)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

add_executable(helloqt ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(helloqt Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)
` Sorry I'm not sure how to make this comment look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this under project(helloqt):

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
```

Comment: he doesn't define any own `QObject` or any UI so this has not impact on this issue.